# Render react component from a different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built a react component which I would like to render from within a second component in a separate file.

StoryStrap.react.js

```
var React = require('react');
import { Input, ButtonInput, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';

var StoryStrap = React.createClass({ 

  render: function() {

    return (
        <div>
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Headline" />
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Subline" />
        </div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = StoryStrap;
```

How can I display this component from the return method of a second component in a different file?

MainSection.react.js

```
return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row row-grid">
            <section id="ROTopBar" className="ro-topBar box-shadow--2dp">

                <div id="storyStraps" className="col-md-4">
                    <h4>Story Straps</h4>
                    <StoryStrap /> //Display storyStrap component here
                </div>

                <div id="storyNames" className="col-md-4">
                    <h4>Name</h4>
                </div>

                <div id="storyInfo" className="col-md-4">
                    <h4>Info</h4>
                </div>

            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: So your question is about sharing variables across scripts? Have you ever written modular javascript? You are using a mixture (for some reason) of `require` and `import` so you already have the ability to import it..?

Answer (score 1):

You need to require the component.

```
var StoryStrap = require('./StoryStrap.react.js');
```

Then you can use `<StoryStrap />` in your render function.

It's probably best to try and be consistent with your module import/export syntax. Either use the new ES6 module syntax or the older commonjs style.

#### Default Export

```
// ES6 modules
export default React.createClass({ ... });

// ES5 & commonjs
module.exports = React.createClass({ ... });
```

#### Default Import

```
// ES6 modules
import StoryStrap from './StoryStrap.react.js';

// ES5 & commonjs
var StoryStrap = require('./StoryStrap.react.js');
```

#### Named Exports

```
// ES6 modules
export const StoryStrap = React.createClass({ ... });

// ES5 & commonjs
exports.StoryStrap = React.createClass({ ... });
```

#### Named Import

```
// ES6 modules
import { StoryStrap } from './StoryStrap.react.js';

// ES5 & commonjs
var StoryStrap = require('./StoryStrap.react.js').StoryStrap;
```

Comment: doesn't need the extension

Comment: Nope, it doesn't  but the asker is clearly new to modules and they've used a strange file extension, so I thought it would be best to be explicit.

Comment: Hi Have tried exactly what have written, but nothing is returned when I utilise <StoryStrap /> not even any console errors.

Comment: Try `console.log(StoryStrap)` from your main section file. See what comes out.

Comment: nothing seems to come out in the console at all, although I have just seen this error: `Warning: the query argument to createHref is deprecated; use a location descriptor instead`

But is todo with the React Router

Comment: Is the `console.log` statement definitely being run? You can test by adding a breakpoint to that line in your devtools and reloading the page to see whether it stops.

Comment: The react router warning can be fixed by changing your `history` dep to `~0.13.x` if I recall

Comment: Ok, So I am not 100% sure what I have done, but it is now working a combination of fixing various errors helps.

1st there the app was building properly so I wasn't actually seeing ,y changes reflected in the browser. Then when it did build, i was able to fix the react-router error and then it told me there were syntax errors in the StoryStrap.react.js file, fixed those and boom! It work now.

I wouldnt have got there without you though. Thank you.